# I have tried the following code but it is printing all the inputs as lucky. Can anyone help me understand the mistake

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int checklucky(char *a);
int main()
{
    int c;
    char name[100];
    scanf("%s",name);
    c=checklucky(name);
    if(c==1)
        printf("%s is luvky",a);
    else
        printf("%s is not lucky",a);
    return 0;
}
int checklucky(char  *a)
{
    int sum=0,len,i;
    len=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+name[i];
    }
    if(sum%2==0)
        return (1);
    else 
        return (0);
}
```

A string is said to be "lucky" if the sum of the ASCII values of the characters in the string is even.

The function accepts a pointer to a string and returns an int.

The return value is `1` if the string is "lucky" and `0` otherwise.

Comment: That's not your real (copied and pasted) code, is it? You should make up your mind where to use `a` and where to use `name`. Other than that, your code looks okay.

Comment: Maybe all the strings you have inputted really *are* lucky? Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code line by line to see it does what you expect it to?

Comment: maybe also just try to print the sum and see if the expected number appears.

Comment: This code is not compiling at all. But when the `a/name` things are fixed it is working: https://ideone.com/mkxdhY

Comment: For your actual code: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

In your checklucky function, you are using 'name' variable which is not a local nor a global variable. You should use 'a' local variable:

```
int checkLucky(char *a)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for( ; *a != 0; a++ )
        sum += (int)*a;
    return (sum % 2 == 0);
}
```